# How to use user defined class in deque?

Tags: c++, stl

```
class Node
{
    int x,y;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int x, int y);
    Node();
};
```

How do I make a deque using this?

```
deque<Node> balBinaryTree;
```

gives me errors

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

---edit---

---edit---
also should I do

```
  deque<Node> balBinaryTree;
```

or

```
  deque<Node*> balBinaryTree;
```

Comment: both `deque<Node>` and `deque<Node*>` are correct. If you use the first one, a **copy** of the Node object you push_back in the deque will be added at the end of container. You should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <deque>
std::deque<Node> balBinaryTree;
```

> also should I do
>
> `deque<Node> balBinaryTree;` or
>
> `deque<Node*> balBinaryTree;`

You should decide it yourself.
`deque<Node>` leads to unnecessary copying.
`deque<Node*>` leads to possible memory management problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>
std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Node>> balBinaryTree;
```

This takes care of the memory management for you and means you wont have to worry about the memory management explicitly.

Note: you are using naked pointers in your Node, so be careful and make sure the lifetime of the objects outlast the raw pointers so you don't leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using:

`deque<Node> balBinaryTree`

You'll probably want to use the emplace calls

`balBinaryTree.emplace_back(x,y)` 
to invoke the constructor and insert at the same time. Will avoid having to deal with memory management as you would need to do for `deque<Node*>` and avoid the extra copies occurring as would be the case in:

```
deque<Node> balBinaryTree;
Node inst_node(10,20); 
balBinaryTree.push_back( inst_node )
```